# How to return multiple values from an ajax success event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two js files i.e. myJs1.js and myJs2.js .
From myJs1.js a method of myJs2.js is called.

I want to return `r1` and `r2` into results(in myJs1.js)

I have tried this:
I declared `r1` and `r2` variables before the ajax call and 
after the ajax call I added:

```
return [r1,r2];
```

But it return `r1` and `r2` as `undefined`.
When I researched the issue I came across that adding `async: false` could work but it has so many issues (like browser freezing). Even so I tried it and still was not able to get the values of `r1` and r2.

Note: I am uing AJAX for the first time so bear that in mind.

---

EDIT: There is an ajax call in Js1 in which on success event the method is called. I want to access the result to call another method in the js1

EDIT:LOOK HERE FOR THE CODE

myJS1:

```
function method() 
{

$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/***/***",
    success: function(response){
        result=methodOfmyJs2(response);
        load1(r1); //r1 from result
        load2(r2); //r2 from result
    }
})
```

}

myJs2 :

```
function methodOfmyJs2(data)
{
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    data:SomeData,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/***/***",
    success: function(response){
      r1=anotherMethodFromThisJS1(response);
      r2=anotherMethodFromThisJS2(response); 
      result=[r1,r2]
    }
})
```

}

I need to access the value of r1 and r2 to call load1 and load2 method of myJs1.

Comment: wtf this _is_ jquery

Comment: You can't return values from an asynchronous operation. It makes no sense. And you're already using jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The function that you pass to `success` property is a callback and it will be invoked when a valid response is available. You don't have to return anything from this method. Just use the response and update any variables or views if you need to

Comment: @nem i have edited the question properly now. I dnt think it is completly duplicate.

Comment: @pointy soory, "no jquery" was copied from somewhere by mistake. i didnt notice it.

Comment: @AmanGupta please include the code where you're having trouble accessing the values afterward as well. I think some of the context is lost, and that's making it difficult for everyone to understand your problem.

Comment: @Mic I have tried my best to explain my issue and updated the code as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax calls are `asynchronous` by default, meaning ajax call function `jQuery.ajax()` wont wait for the HTTP response to come back before returning.

To get the data after the HTTP response has arrived we have to provide a callback, that's `success` function. If you want to get this data inside another function just call that function inside `success` callback.

Following is the code:

```
//JS1.
function processResponse(r1, r2) {
    // do processing here with r1 and r2
}

//JS2.
function methodOfmyJs2()
{
     $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        data:somedata,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/****/****",
        success: function(response){
            r1=anotherMethodFromThisJS1(response);
            r2=anotherMethodFromThisJS2(response); 

            //calling the success callback
            processResponse(r1, r1);
        }  
    }); 
}
```

There's another option if you really want to do it, you can make your Ajax call `synchronous` like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: remote_url,
    async: false,//now call is synchronous
    success : function (data) {
    }
});
```

Now `jQuery.ajax()` will wait till HTTP response has arrived, then you can return  `[r1, r2]` from `methodOfmyJs2()`.

However you should avoid making synchronous calls as it will make the JS thread wait freezing the UI.

Comment: Can you please look at the question again.i have edited it now properly. Soory for the inconvinince.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a callback instead.

[EDIT]

myJS1:

```
function method () {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/***/***",
        success: function (response) {
            methodOfmyJS2(function (r1, r2) {
                load1(r1);
                load2(r2);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

myJS2:

```
methodOfmyJs2 (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: somedata,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/****/****",
        success: function (response) {
            var r1 = anotherMethodFromThisJS1(response);
            var r2 = anotherMethodFromThisJS2(response);

            callback(r1, r2);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.I have edited the question code " method call has a parameter "data" ". How about that.

Comment: Can you please look at the question again.i have edited it now properly. Soory for the inconvinince.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say in the edit. You want to access the result of one ajax call into another ajax call ?

Comment: on success of ajax of js1, method of js2 is called with a parameter, in this method there is a ajax call and on success of it i want to return the result back in the success of first ajax where some other method is called with the result.

Comment: I edited my post. I think I unterstood now your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` returns [promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise), which can be chained with [then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

```
function getAjaxOutput() {
    request1().then(function(data){
      // get data from request 1 and pass to request 2
      return request2(data);        
    })
  .then(function(data){
   // get data from request2
    $('#output').text(JSON.stringify(data));
  })
    return false;
}
```

try it
https://jsfiddle.net/je7wf4ww/

and if u want to return plain result from getAjaxOutput - u simply can't (without making request sync of course) - u need to return promise which is a wrapper around ajax call and chain it again with `then`